# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel-5.8

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `reports` (`patient_name`, `gender`, `ic`, `phone`, `current_location`, `status`, `emg_code`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (dfd, female, sdf, sdf, sdf, sdf, sdf, 2022-06-13 05:53:11, 2022-06-13 05:53:11))

May I know how can I solve this? The user_id is the foreign key of the Users Table.

Users Table:

```
  Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('profile_image');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');

            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

User Model:

```
public function reports()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Report::class);
}
```

Reports Table:

```
  Schema::create('reports', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->string('patient_name');
        $table->string('gender');
        $table->string('ic');
        $table->string('phone');
        $table->string('current_location');
        $table->string('status');
        $table->string('emg_code');
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();

       
        $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

    });
```

ReportController Create func.:

```
  public function create()
    {
        $users = User::select('id', 'name')->get();
        $users = $users->pluck('name');

        return view('admin.reports.create', compact('users'));
    }
```

ReportController Store func.:

```
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'patient_name' => 'required|string',
            'gender' => ['required', 'in:male,female'],
            'ic' => 'required|string',
            'phone' => 'required|string',
            'current_location' => 'required|string',
            'status' => 'required|string',
            'emg_code' => 'required|string'

        ]);
        $requestData = $request->all();

        $report = Report::create($requestData);


        foreach ($request->users as $user) {
            $report->assignUser($user);
        }

        return redirect('admin/reports')->with('flash_message', 'Report added!');
    }
```

HasUser Trait:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function assignUser($user)
    {
        return $this->users()->save(
            User::whereName($user)->firstOrFail()
        );
}
```

Reports Model:

```
class Report extends Model
{
    use HasUser;
    
          protected $fillable = [
                'user_id',
                'patient_name',
                'gender',
                'ic',
                'phone',
                'current_location',
                'status',
                'emg_code'
            ];

}
```

Comment: Use `::make` instead of `::create`, add the user, then `save()` the report

Comment: Hi @brombeer I edited the code to `$report = Report::make($requestData); $report->save();` but it still shows the same problem. Is there any wrong with what I have edited?

Comment: Can you try change to this , $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();

Comment: set default value instead of user_id `$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->default(0); `

Comment: Hi, @FaizulIslam I tried and it shows this, SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Comment: Hi,@Xun I also tried your solution, but it shows the 404|Not Found error

Comment: "_I edited the code to $report = Report::make($requestData); $report->save();_" Did you add the users (your foreach) _before_ saving?

Comment: okay then you add send user_id when save data `$requestData = $request->all();` add `user_id` in your requested data array

Comment: @brombeer Yes, I did. The Users Table already has the data. I was able to show the list of users in the form but I was unable to save it when I am creating a report and assigning it to the user.

Comment: @FaizulIslam, sorry. I don't understand what you mean. Do you mean I need to add something like `$report->user_id = $request->user_id `?